# html5 facebook like button not rendering in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer

My current html5 facebook like button is not rendering in IE.

My page is: http://www.giovannamalacarne.com/it/collezione/art-panels-brillanti.html

Does anyone know why this is not working?

Comment: Not meant to be snarky, but... Don't expect all browsers to support Html5 at the same level?  As with all past instances of major changes to HTML including the browser wars of the early web, it's a simple fact of life that not all browsers display the same thing the same way (or at all).  Html5 is no different.

Comment: Sure i am aware of that cross-browser issues. My site is in XHTML. I use HTML5 button as it has fewer validation issues.I also use the HTML5 button on a different website without any problems in IE - http://www.jeyjoo.com/gallery/img-anna-fitzpatrick-tennis-636.htm

Comment: Does it render if you call the iFrame source directly from the addressbar? Which IE version are you testing against?

Comment: I could use iFrame version, but my point is that the HTML 5 works on oither pages but not this, so I'd like to sort out the problem.

Comment: did you ever find out why? I'm having similar problems :(

Comment: Try removing the `<!-- and //-->` that you used while including the Facebook html5 like button code.

Answer (score 0):

You could detect using JS if IE8(or lower) and overwrite the div with the iframe version.